# Can Angular App act as an Authenticated USER for RTDB?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

No code here just question.

I would like to allow only authenticated users to read from RTDB, but I would not like every user to sign up. What I would prefer is to have one login that is tied to the angular app that would be activated for every user who accesses the app.

I know that should be possible, but it's not a normal use so I find it hard to get proper examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really a supported use case.  Firebase Authentication is meant to uniquely identify end users by the accounts that they create.  In particular, it's a security measure meant to sandbox end users from each other so they each have specific access to things that only they should access.  It's not meant to allow uncontrolled use of a single account.

You could try to implement something where your app code always signs in to a single user account with a preset email and password (you would have to code those strings directly into your app and they would essentially be public from that point, and *there are no workarounds to hide this data*).  But I don't see how this helps anything at all from the perspective of building an application.  What this does is allow the entire world to use this one account and all of its privileges.  It is no more "secure" than allowing full access using no authentication at all.  I don't recommend it, and I think it would only cause you problems in the future.